# SQL Server - Dúvida Query melhor vendedor de um cliente

Tags: sql

Na tabela loja venda, tenho o código do cliente e do vendedor, preciso saber com qual vendedor o mesmo cliente comprou o maior numero de vezes ou o mais recente e apareça na query abaixo. Não faço ideia de como fazer isso, uma subquery talvez?

```
select

--LV.VENDEDOR,

cv.CODIGO_CLIENTE,

DATEDIFF(D,CV.ULTIMA_COMPRA, GETDATE())AS RECENCIA,

COUNT(TICKET) as FREQUENCIA,

CONVERT(NUMERIC(14,2),AVG(VALOR_PAGO))AS TICKET_MEDIO,

DATEDIFF(YY,CV.ANIVERSARIO, GETDATE())AS IDADE,

CV.PROFISSAO,
CV.UF,
CV.CIDADE,
CV.BAIRRO

from LOJA_VENDA lv
inner join clientes_varejo cv
on cv.codigo_cliente = lv.CODIGO_CLIENTE

where DATA_VENDA between DateAdd(DD,-90,GETDATE() ) and DateAdd(DD,-1,GETDATE() )
and lv.CODIGO_CLIENTE is not null
and VALOR_CANCELADO='0.00'
and VALOR_PAGO>'0'

GROUP BY cv.codigo_cliente, cv.CLIENTE_VAREJO,cv.ULTIMA_COMPRA,cv.ANIVERSARIO,cv.PROFISSAO,cv.UF,cv.CIDADE,cv.BAIRRO

ORDER BY cv.CLIENTE_VAREJO
```

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

Experimente esse código abaixo:

```
select
LV.VENDEDOR,
cv.CODIGO_CLIENTE,
DATEDIFF(D,MAX(CV.ULTIMA_COMPRA), GETDATE())AS RECENCIA,
count(cv.CODIGO_CLIENTE) as frequencia,
CONVERT(NUMERIC(14,2),AVG(VALOR_PAGO))AS TICKET_MEDIO,
--não é possível adicionar as colunas abaixo usando o group by que você deseja
/*
DATEDIFF(YY,CV.ANIVERSARIO, GETDATE())AS IDADE, 
CV.PROFISSAO,
CV.UF,
CV.CIDADE,
CV.BAIRRO
*/
from LOJA_VENDA lv
inner join clientes_varejo cv
on cv.codigo_cliente = lv.CODIGO_CLIENTE
```

Caso deseje encontrar os dados acima, é necessário unificá-los de algum forma para se adequar ao group by

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).